# How can i test this model to classify a single image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

```
imgdata = []
labels = []
compressed_img_size = 32
celltypes = ['im_Koilocytotic', 'im_Metaplastic', 'im_Dyskeratotic', 'im_Parabasal', 'im_Superficial-Intermediate']
path = ["./CervicalDataset/" + celltype  + "/" + celltype + "/CROPPED/" for celltype in celltypes]

# Low pass filter
LOW_PASS_FILTER = False
# High pass filter
HIGH_PASS_FILTER = False

cur_label = -1
for celltype in path:
    cur_label += 1
    # Iterate over each cell's individual image
    cellimages = os.listdir(celltype)
    for cellimage in cellimages:
        if cellimage.lower().endswith(".bmp"):
            # Mark each cell with a cell type
            labels.append(cur_label)
            img = cv2.imread(celltype+cellimage)
            img = np.array(Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB').resize((compressed_img_size, compressed_img_size)))
            if LOW_PASS_FILTER:
                img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
            elif HIGH_PASS_FILTER:
                img = img - cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT) + 127
            imgdata.append(img)

labels = np.array(labels)
imgdata = np.array(imgdata)

# Shuffle/randomize order
random_order = np.arange(imgdata.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(random_order)
labels = labels[random_order]
imgdata = imgdata[random_order]

# Get # of each cell type
unique, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
print(np.asarray((unique, counts)).T)
    
for i in range(0, len(labels)):
    # Replace this with 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 depending on the type of figure being generated
    if labels[i] == 2:
        disp_img(i)
        break
        
# Initialize neural networks
model_efficientnet = EfficientNetB7(weights=None, include_top = False)
features_efficientnet = model_efficientnet.predict(imgdata, batch_size=32)

cur = features_efficientnet
extracted_features = []
zipped_data = zip(cur, labels)
for cur, label in zipped_data:
    cur = np.append(cur.reshape(cur.shape[0] * cur.shape[1] * cur.shape[2]), label)
    extracted_features.append(cur)
extracted_features = np.array(extracted_features)

# Use min-max scaling to normalize the data
X = extracted_features[:, 0:-1]
y = extracted_features[:, -1]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

pca = PCA(n_components = 0.95) # represent 95% of the variation through principal components
pca.fit(scaled_X)
pca_x = pca.transform(scaled_X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pca_x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 49)

# Neural network for classification
model = Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(rate=0.8),
    Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',  optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I want to classify one test image using the model above.  I have tried  using model.predict , but I am getting the following error :

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2341, in predict_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2327, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2315, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.predict_step(data)
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2283, in predict_step
    return self(x, training=False)
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 15), found shape=(None, 32, 32, 3)
```

Also , here is how I am using the model to test an image:

```
# Load and preprocess the single image
image_path = "./test/038.png"  # Replace with the path to your image
image_size = (compressed_img_size, compressed_img_size)  # Match the expected input size
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image = np.array(Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB').resize(image_size))

# Make predictions
predicted_probabilities = model.predict(np.expand_dims(image, axis=0))

# Interpret the predictions
predicted_class = np.argmax(predicted_probabilities)
predicted_class_name = celltypes[predicted_class][len('im_'):]

print(f"The predicted class is: {predicted_class_name}")
```

My train set consists of images of .bmp type , 2048 x 1536 pixels. The image I am testing with is just copy-pasted from the dataset.

Please advise on how I can do this. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the full error message output for this? There is a lot going on and that may help pin down the specific problem if we have the traceback info.

Comment: I'm not sure what the shape of your training data is (take a look at that), but you can try to change `Flatten(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)),` to `Flatten(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),`. The error shows that there is something wrong with the image shape you give to the sequential model.

Comment: Hello , I have updated the above code with the relevant details. Please have another look , thank you !